# List indexes - If too big go back to the beginning of the list

Tags: python, list, for-loop, indexing

So,  maybe this question will sound very beginnerish, but I just don't know how I should begin with this example:

So the example is:
I have a list for example 13 items long (1,2,3,4...13)
There's a given number, let's say 6

The program needs to show me in a list, in what order are the numbers going to fall out. If the second number is 6, it means every time the sixth item is the next whcih is going to fall out. But my problem is that how could I tell python that if the index number goes up too high, it should start counting again from the beggining?

This is what I made myself so far

```
x = int(input("Number of items (numbers): "))
y = int(input("Fall-out number: "))
#n = 1
#id = 0
numbers = [n for n in range(x+1)]
fallsout = []
numbers.remove(30)

for i in numbers:
    if i % y == 0:
        fallsout.append(i)

print (numbers)
print (fallsout)
```

Here's an example what should be in the input and output:

Input:
x = 13
y = 6

Output: 6 12 5 13 8 3 1 11 2 7 4 10 9

Comment: I don't understand your question. Can you show an example in put and your expected output?

Comment: Could you provide us with sample `x` and `y` and the expected output?

Comment: what's Gyerekek? please translate to English and provide expected output

Comment: It sounds like the modulus operator is what you're looking for. Using `x % 13` will return the remainder of x after division by 13. This will loop through your list without using an out of bounds index.

Comment: Just edited the post to make it more understandable

Comment: is `Output: 6 12 5 13 8 3 1 11 2 7 4 10` what should be in `fallsout` ??

Comment: @NathanBlaine Output should be fallsout. Sorry I didn't mention it.

Comment: 1 more q for you - should the output be 12 elems (what you listed) or 14 elems (the number of elems in `elems`) ?

Comment: @NathanBlaine The output should be 13 elems (Note that I delete the 0 in the code at the beginning, because I only need the numbers from 1 to 13.)

Comment: @ÁdámGutási why do you go from 5 -> 13, should this be 6 12 5 11 ?

Comment: @NathanBlaine no,no , 13 is correct. 13 is the 6th number from 5, because 6 fell out already, and 12 too: ((6),7,8,9,10,11,(12),13 )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, looks like you want to copy every 6th element from numbers into fallout and then remove the element from numbers, and continue on in a cyclic fashion until numbers is empty.

```
import copy

x = int(input("Number of items (numbers): "))
y = int(input("Fall-out number: "))
# list should start from 1 as by the example
numbers = [n for n in range(1,x+1)]
# deep copy to preserve original list
numbers_copy = copy.deepcopy(numbers)
fallsout = []

count = y
while len(numbers_copy)!=0:
    fallsout.append(numbers_copy[count-1])
    # remove element
    del numbers_copy[count-1]
    # handle starting edge
    if count == 0:
        count = 1
    # handle last edge
    if numbers_copy != []:
        count = (count+y-1)%len(numbers_copy)

print numbers
print fallsout
```

Output is

```
Number of items (numbers): 13
Fall-out number: 6
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]
[6, 12, 5, 13, 8, 3, 1, 11, 2, 7, 4, 10, 9]
```

**Explanation**:

Suppose I have a array numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6] of length=6, and I am using an counter "count" to iterate through the list. So that,

> numbers[count] = 2 (when count=1)

Then to look at the next element, I would use numbers[count+1].
To jump back to the starting of the list, we use modulus operation,

> count = (count+number_of_steps)%len(numbers)

eg, at index=4 and to jump 3 steps, next index would be (4+3)%6 = 1
Now we have to copy every yth element from the list,so we use,

```
fallsout.append(numbers_copy[count-1]) # count-1 as we are counting from 0
```

Then we remove that number from the list,

```
del numbers_copy[count-1]
```

Then we jump forward count by y steps by modulus as discussed above,

```
count = (count+y-1)%len(numbers_copy) # again -1 as we count from 0
```

The length of numbers needs to be calculated again as the list could change due to deleting of elements.

Comment: That was it I was looking for! Thank you!

Comment: Glad to help :)

Comment: Can you maybe explain a bit more how the while here works? I can't really understand it.

Comment: I have added an explanation, hope it helps